# Python - Sorting Through List With A Line Code

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list according to my specification with a single line of code instead of 2 lines of code, i can assign variable names in a for loop
as shown in the sample code but i can't sort using a for loop

my current code works fine but i have to zip 2 lists (new, new2) to finally be able to sort, anyway way to just do it in a single line of code to get 'symbol' and 'priceChange'?

```
sample = [{'symbol': 'APPL', 'priceChange': '-5.916', 'bidPrice': '0.03201500'}, 
{'symbol': 'URZ', 'priceChange': '2.916', 'bidPrice': '0.03201500'}]


stock = ['APPL']


new = [i['priceChange'] for i in sample if i['symbol'] in stock]
new2 = [i['symbol'] for i in sample if i['symbol'] in stock]

result = list(zip(new2, new))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not this

```
new = [[i['priceChange'],i['symbol']] for i in sample if i['symbol'] in stock]
```

Comment: thank you i tried something similar but didn't add the brackets.

Comment: Note that this outputs a list of lists, rather than a list of tuples, which the OP's code outputs.